# Codeigniter, Select, Result, Array Format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter, I selected all (*) data from two tables (`country` and `city`). Those tables have an `ID` fields, when I print the result there is only one `ID` element in array.

**The country table's fields:**

1. id;
2. name;
3. flag;
4. president.

**The city table's fields:**

1. id;
2. ctry_id; (country id)
3. name.

**This is my codeigniter code:**

```
$this->db->select('country.*, city.*');
$this->db->from('country');
$this->db->join('city', 'city.ctry_id = country.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('country.name', 'Tajikistan');
$qry = $this->db->get();

// Testing purpose only [do not judge ;)]
echo '<pre>';
print_r($qry->result());
echo '</pre>';
```

**Expected result:**

```
id => 1,
name => 'Tajikistan',
flag => 'tj.png',
president => 'Emomali Rahmon',
id => 1,
ctry_id => 1,
name => 'Dushanbe'
.
.
.
```

**Result that I got:**

```
id => 1,
name => 'Dushanbe',
flag => 'tj.png',
president => 'Emomali Rahmon',
ctry_id => 1
.
.
.
```

> Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Simply write one param in select `country.id as country_id`

Comment: but an array cannot contain a same key

Comment: @HastaDhana: yes I did realize...

Comment: then you could use alias for the `id`s column as Akhil suggested

Comment: @HastaDhana: yes I just dont want to write every field in select statement

Comment: @AkhilVL: Thanks a lot! )))

Comment: You missed to join `companies`/`company` table?

Comment: @Tpojka ???????

Comment: Now problem has more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this 'problem' using pseudonym, or prefix for every column, for example:

```
The country table's fields:
    ctry_id;
    ctry_name;
    ctry_flag;
    ctry_president.

The city table's fields:
    cty_id;
    cty_ctry_id; (country id)
    cty_name.
```